# Excel, nest counta function into range of sum function

Tags: excel, sum

I want to expand range of sum when new cells are added in down.

My first try was nesting counta function into range of sum function but it didn't work.

=SUM(I4&":I"&COUNTA(I:I))

Anyone has any idea about how to do it?

Comment: You may try `=SUM(I4:INDEX(I4:I50000,COUNT(I4:I50000)))`.

Answer (score 0):

The shown solution does not work when there is an empty cell in the SUM range
It would be safer to just use:

```
=SUM(I:Ï)
```

to summarize the entire column.

If summing the entire column isn't possible I suggest to make an *Excel Table* column out of your data.
Excel Tables adjust automatically when new data is added. This is best practice.